# Count and replace all vowels in a textbox

Tags: c#

I need to count all vowels and replace it with the letter x, in a textbox. I managed to do the counting part and here's the code, but i'm having problem with replacing all vowels in the textbox with the letter x. Can someone help me?

```
int total = 0;

string sentence = textBox1.Text.ToLower();
char[] vowels = { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};                   
{
      total++;
}

total = sentence.Count(c => vowels.Contains(c));
MessageBox.Show("There are " + total++ " vowels";

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
```

**EDIT 1**:

Thank you all for helping. For some reason the vowels in my textbox doesnt change!!! It does the counting but no replacement of the letter x. I've tried all the solutions here, but still nothing happens to my the vowels in the textbox.

Comment: You have to assign the content of `senetnce` to your textbox. Only because you say `sentence = textboax1.Value` doesn´t mean that changes to `sentence` are reflected in the textbox also, as strings are immutable. See my edit.

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach(char vowel in vowels)
    sentence = sentence.Replace(vowel, 'x');
```

---

> For some reason the vowels in my textbox doesnt change!!! It does the
>   counting but no replacement of the letter x. I've tried all the
>   solutions here, but still nothing happens to my the vowels in the
>   textbox.

The textbox and the string are not linked with each other. So if you change the string you won't change the `TextBox.Text`. You have to re-assign the new value:

```
textBox1.Text = sentence; // after you have used Replace like shown above
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use *Linq*:

```
sentence = string.Concat(sentence.Select(c => vowels.Contains(c) ? 'x' : c));
```

Comment: How elegant :)!

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple regex:

```
var r = new Regex("[aeiouy]");
sentence = r.Replace(sentence, "x");
```

EDIT: As strings are immutable changes to `sentence` are not reflected in your textbox, so you have to re-assign its value:

```
textBox1.Text = sentence;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a `ForEach` `Linq`-Expression and `string.Replace` method:

```
vowels.ToList().ForEach(vowel => sentence = sentence.Replace(vowel, 'x'));
```

**EDIT 1:**

You could also try a `for`-loop as you also tried in your question:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++) {
    if(vowels.Contains((char)sentence[i])) {
        sentence[i] = 'x';
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

To write the value of `sentence` back to the `TextBox` add the following:

```
textBox1.Text = sentence;
```

Comment: Thank you all for helping. For some reason nothing happens on my textbox when I click the button... the label counts correct number of vowels.. but I've now tried all of your tips but nothing happens..

Comment: @Lini You mean no replacement?

Comment: @Lini I edited my post. If it is useful, please upvote the answer.

Comment: thank you, for some reason vowels is marked red in vowels.Contains... I've tried this code before. It says "char[] does not contain a definition of Contain"

Answer (score 0):

Why not maybe simply try with a regular expresion, as the colleague above has already suggested?

Something like:

string text = "Here comes some text";

```
        string vowels = @"([aeiou])";
        Regex regex = new Regex(vowels);

        Match match = regex.Match(text);
```

and then maybe continue your logic with some collection and a foreach cycle()in wich you do the replacing with a char/string "x".